# unable to connect to my ftp server

Tags: ftp

I have a computer on which I log in ssh quite simply. I would like to host my site on this computer and I installed proftpd as ftp server but when I try to connect to my server from another computer with filezilla, I get this error:

```
Status: Disconnected from the server
Status: Connection to 192.168.43.69:21 ...
Status: Connection established, waiting for the greeting message ...
Status: Server not secure, this one does not support FTP on TLS.
Command: USER root
Answer: 331 Password required for root
Order: PASS *****
Answer: 530 Incorrect authentication.
Error: Critical error: Can not connect to server
```

I use the password of my account linux the result is the same, I use the secret phrase that served to encrypted my key ssh the same message always appears.

I even created another linux user without root privileges but I still have the same error.

Help me please!

Comment: `Server not secure, this one does not support FTP on TLS` you may want to consider changing your passwords as they may be compromised.

Comment: I try with multiple users and several different passwords the result is the same.

Comment: You're trying to log in as root over ftp without TLS?

Comment: I even try with a user without root privillege the result is the same

Comment: I'm happy to see ProFTPd does not allow root logins over FTP. That's a feature.

Comment: I can not do it even with a normal user

Comment: What about user list ?

Comment: i don't no know how to create an ftp user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to log in using the sftp protocol and it works fine! It seems that it is much more secure than ftp so I recommend it to all beginners in network administration!